# ConfigurationManager unrecognized despite using System.Configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, configuration

I am writing a Front End program for a database using XAML for the UI & C# for the logic. I'm trying to read in the database by doing the following:

```
//Declaring VFWPost table
//Note: This table is used in the "VFW Posts" tab.
DataTable tblVFWPost = new DataTable();
string connString1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["C:\Users\Sam Brockmann\Documents\VSS Database.accdb"].ConnectionString;
string query1 = @"SELECT VFW Post #, Post Manager ID, Annual Due Date, Post Address, Post City, Post Zip Code, 
    Post Phone Number, Post Email FROM tblVFWPost";

//Fill the VFWPost Set with the data
using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connString1))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query1, conn1);
    da1.Fill(tblVFWPost);
}

//Setting VFWPost Listbox item source
List<DataRow> VFWPostList = tblVFWPost.AsEnumerable().ToList();
VFWPostListBox.ItemsSource = VFWPostList;
```

The problem is that Visual Studio refuses to recognize the ConfigurationManager class, despite having "using System.Configuration;" up with the other namespaces I am using. Are there alternatives to the ConfigurationManager class that could be used to pull database information into my program directly?

Comment: Did you also add the assembly as a reference as part of your project?

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that class comes from the System.Configuration assembly. You need to add that to your project as a reference from the global assembly cache.

Comment: At the risk of sounding dumb, how do I do that?

Comment: Right click on your project, select "Add reference". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx